# About validation in struts 2 - First validation ok next yields wrong page

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

I am having a slight issue with validation in struts2 during consecutive validations.Now if an error is found on the form for the first time the correct url is used such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/Appname/Secure/AddAction.action
```

However if there is an error on the form during second time validation The resulting url is used (This url is wrong)

```
 http://localhost:8080/Appname/AddAction.action
```

This is what i have in struts.xml

```
 <action name="AddAction" class="controller.AddAction">
            <param name="dR"></param>
            <param name="dS"></param>
            <result name="input">/Secure/AddAction.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="redirect">
                <param name="location">/Secure/AddAction.jsp?msg=${msg}</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Any suggestions on how i cld fix the problem

Edit: Update:
So in the validation i put the following code

```
HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            String r = request.getRequestURI();
```

The first time its    : /Appname/Secure/AddAction.action

But the next time its : /Appname/AddAction.action

How can i make them same both times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which namespace located your action? default or Secure? try this maybe:

```
<action name="/Secure/AddAction" class="controller.AddAction">
            <param name="dR"></param>
            <param name="dS"></param>
            <result name="input">/Secure/AddAction.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/Error.jsp</result>
            <result name="success" type="redirect">
                <param name="location">/Secure/AddAction.jsp?msg=${msg}</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

Comment: I get the following The requested resource (/Appname/Secure/AddAction) is not available.

Comment: @AdamZedan do u wanna have AddAction unter the namespace "/Secure" or default?

Comment: I just resolved the problem by placing it under a separate namespace. Initially it was under default with no namespace

Comment: @AdamZedan i'd like to suggest u **config-browser-plugin** for sturt2, it is very helpful, if you got similar problem..